# Unable to copy/paste CDF embed code in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, version-9, cdf-format

I tried this question in superuser but no luck, maybe somebody here knows what is going on...

Mathematica offers export to a format they call Computed Document Format (CDF) - it is basically a player for the notebooks you work in that environment.

One way to use them is to embed it on a web page. While the pop-up window that generates the embed code offers a way to copy the code to the clip board (this is under Ubuntu), it doesn't appear to register and there is nothing to paste once I get to the text editor to incorporated it in my web page.

Any suggestions of what might be amiss would be appreciated. Is there a secondary clipboard where the text goes? Copy/paste works fine otherwise in this software...

I run Mathematica 9.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did you try CDFInformation and CDFDeploy? Why use a a pop-up window anyway?

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. The wizard they provide from the file menu seemed a nice way to generate the embed code but this should provide a path forward!